# How to show a saving / saved message when binding objects in Firebase / AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm binding a users details to a section in Firebase like so:

```
var userDetails = firebase.child('users').child(userID);
$firebaseObject(userDetails).$bindTo($scope, 'user');
```

I have some HTML form which binds the data to to various parts of the user (ex. `ng-model=user.Name`)

I'm trying to figure out how when the HTML item is changed it show's a div with a message that says "Saving" and then a message that says "Saved" once the Firebase update is completed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [$save method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-save) to the rescue for that. It's called on model change i.e. `ng-change`

```
//html
<input type="text" ng-model="userObj.name" ng-change="userObj.$save(user)" />


//js
var userObj = $firebaseObject(ref);

userObj.$save().then(function(ref) {

  $scope.notifyUserSaved()//here you do notification

}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

**UPD. Using rootScope:**

```
//in controller 
userObj.$save().then(function(ref) {

  //$scope.notifyUserSaved()
  //here you do notification
  $rootScope.$broadcast("saving", {"foo":"bar"});

}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error:", error);
});

//in other modules
$rootScope.$on("saving", function(){
  //notify user globally here
})
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this globally? ex. Watch if any updates are occuring to show a saving message if so.

Comment: $rootScope is an equivalent of 'global' scope in AngularJS applications. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope . Check the updated post